# Are medical prescriptions for medical imaging or physiotherapy sessions written by physicians located outside the United States recognized in the US?

Tags: usa, health

Are medical prescriptions written by physicians located outside the United States recognized in the United States?

I'm interested in  medical imaging (e.g., MRI or x-ray) and physiotherapy sessions. (see [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/78465/1810) regarding prescriptions for pharmaceutical drugs.)

The recognition (or the lack of) may happen at different levels, such as the federal laws, the state laws, physicians, or the health insurances.

---

Example of MRI prescription ([source](https://redd.it/77nhr9)):

[image]

---

A few related questions on the terminology and laws:

- [Is the paper provided by a physician indicating a patient should do an MRI without referring any business referred to as a prescription or a referral?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/198032/3023)
- [Is it required by law to have a prescription to get an MRI scan in the United States?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/37560/31)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a foreign prescription for a prescription drug filled in the US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78465/getting-a-foreign-prescription-for-a-prescription-drug-filled-in-the-us)

Comment: @KateGregory Thank you, this link is very interesting but doesn't go beyond prescriptions for pharmaceutical drugs. I have subsequently rephrased this question to exclude pharmaceutical drugs and focus on medical imaging and physiotherapy.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the phrasing "prescription" for ordering a test. Would the expectation be that the test results would be sent to the foreign physician, or acted on locally?

Comment: @KateGregory I have added an example of  prescription for ordering a test in the question. The main points of the prescription are 1) making sure that the medical imaging lab understand what needs to be imaged, and what needs to be looked at when analyzing  the image 2) some health insurance plans require to have prescriptions for the medical imaging to be covered. 3) getting access to results faster through the ordering physician, in case the medical imaging lab delay the release of the results (30 days may according to  HIPAA regulations) 4) Some medical imaging labs require prescriptions.

Comment: In the US you'd get a *referral* for an imaging (eg MRI) and a *prescription* for a drug. The referral will be to a specialist for a particular sort of procedure (imaging, blood work, etc.) It is highly unlikely that a referral would transfer internationally.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas [Is the paper provided by a physician indicating the patient should do an MRI without mentioning any lab referred to as a prescription or a referral?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/198032/3023)

Comment: It's a question of terminology. (Usually there's no paper involved.) I work in healthcare (insurance) and this is my understanding of it.

Comment: The big difference is that a prescription is for drugs, and some drugs you cannot legally obtain without a prescription. However it is not illegal to give an MRI without a referral, and in the US you could probably find someone who would do it as long as you could afford the very high costs.

Comment: @DJClayworth [Is it required by law to have a prescription to get an MRI scan in the United States?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/37560/31). Regarding physiotherapy, in some state in some cases one needs a prescription.

Comment: Even within the US you don't normally just walk into the imaging facility with an order on a piece of paper - you have your regular doctor contact the imaging facility and explain what should be done, and they make an appointment for you.  So at the minimum, it would be wise to start by identifying where you would want to do the test, and try to get your doctor to talk to them.  If either your doctor or the facility is unwilling to do that, then you know where you stand.

Comment: @NateEldredge Many (all?) medical imaging labs do not require any referral (= when the physician specify where the patient should go). Examples in Massachusetts: Massachusetts General Hospital, Mount Auburn Hospital, Beth Israel Deaconess Medical Center. But they probably want a prescription (just a guess, I'm not aware of anyone who went there without a prescription).

Comment: Many insurance companies require a referral from a primary care physician before agreeing to pay for a specialist visit. If you skip the referral and pre-authorization steps, your insurer will likely not agree to pay for the service. If you're uninsured, on the other hand, you're free to attempt a walk in, but the service will cost you several thousand dollars and they may not agree to see you without a payment guarantee or up front.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Thanks, I have a  PPO insurance (= I can visit whatever in-network physician or healthcare provider I wish without first requiring a referral from a primary care physician.) Note that out-of-pocket physiotherapy sessions are typically around 100 USD and MRIs can be below 500 USD if shopping for reasonably priced medical imaging labs.

Comment: So if you don't need a referral, then what's the problem? There's no "prescription" for a service like an imaging procedure, so if you manage to find an in-network specialist in a foreign country (doubtful given how messed up the US healthcare system is), then you just go. Though I would personally double check the pre-authorization and medical necessity requirements for the procedure and plan ahead of time.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I'm using those definitions: referral = form in which a physician transfer someone to a specific medical imaging lab; prescription (sometimes named doctor order) = form in which a physician specify that the patient should get some medical imaging (e.g., an MRI) without specifying any medical imaging lab in particular. I opened the question [Is the paper provided by a physician indicating a patient should do an MRI without referring any business referred to as a prescription or a referral?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/198032/3023) to discuss this terminology.

Comment: There is no such thing. I can walk into a radiology center tomorrow and ask for an x-ray, tell them I'm uninsured, and pay out of pocket an exhorbitant fee for an x-ray. Or I can go to a GP/my primary care physician and get a referral for the x-ray if I want the insurance company to pay for it. If you have a PPO plan, you don't need a referral and can walk into any imaging facility in-network and request the procedure to be done. There is no form, because there is no physician transfer -- the physician transfer is *called* a referral. Eg. the PCP *refers you to* the specialist.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Sorry, when you say there is "no such thing", which thing are you referring to?

Comment: Look the point is if you're on a PPO plan, you call up an in-network facility and say "Hello I have XYZ insurance plan and I need a <procedure>." They'll verify your insurance information, and schedule you for an appointment. That is the point. There are no prescriptions, referrals, or whatnot involved.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas PPO only allows to see a specialist without going through a PCP and still be covered by the insurance. But it doesn't allow to directly get medical imaging (if you do, it's not covered, and sometimes it's legally not possible: [Is it required by law to have a prescription to get an MRI scan in the United States?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/37560/31)).