# How many medications can one take on a plane?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, health, local-customs, poland

I have a sick dog and unfortunately the [drug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilostane) is not available in Poland because there is a break in production till June. It is relatively cheap and available in USA and my friend is flying back to Poland in a few days. Hence the question:

Can one fly with such hormonal drug on board? If yes, how many packages can be taken? I need four of them, but I certainly do not want to cause any trouble.

This drug is pills with powder and is a regular prescription drug in Poland.

Comment: is it a pill or liquid? Four what? (a large volume of liquid may mean it has to be in checked luggage) Is the drug controlled in Poland? (customs may have a problem on arrival even if it was ok on the plane.)

Comment: @KateGregory pills with powder, four packages. It is a regular prescription drug in Poland and I do have veterinary prescriptions required. My main concern is international transport law which I am not familiar with.

Comment: Personally, the only issue I see is customs. Note that some products may be legal within a country, but still require additional paperwork/authorizations for import or export. You should probably call customs to check, they should be able to tell you if there are any restrictions for that drug.

Comment: To make sure I would call Polish customs who are available on this number: `+48 33 857 62 51`

Comment: Also, be very clear in checking that the drug is for another person's dog. Rules may be different from medications for one's own use, which are a special case.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78465/getting-a-foreign-prescription-for-a-prescription-drug-filled-in-the-us) answer it turned out that:

> [...] no pharmacy will fill a foreign prescription in the US,
>   controlled substance or not.

Which means I had no way of buying the drug. So I never got to the actual *transportation* step.