# My friend's daughter has been prescribed a platelet-reducing agent Agrylin. Can I buy the above medicine in US and carry it back to India?

Tags: usa, health

My friend's daughter is suffering from a rare condition for which she has been prescribed a platelet-reducing agent Agrylin (not available in India). I am traveling to the US; can I buy the above medicine and carry it back to India?

Comment: Is the prescription from an Indian doctor or an American one? [Filling a foreign prescription in the US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78465/getting-a-foreign-prescription-for-a-prescription-drug-filled-in-the-us) is not going to be possible at the vast majority of pharmacies, and US pharmacies do not (unlike those in some part of the world) dispense prescription medication without a valid prescription.

Comment: Anagrelide is licensed for use in India, and there are even generics manufacturers there. If your friend's daughter's doctor is in India, ask them for advice on getting the prescription filled locally—even if it's not as easy as it should be, I have to imagine there is a way that is easier than flying across the ocean with it